Qt, Масштабируемость интерфейса для экрана с низким разрешением
Windows 10, Qt6
Есть программа с интерфейсом, который разрабатывался под 1920х1080. Проблем с интерфейсом на 2К, 4К и выше нет. Появилась необходимость использовать программу на разрешении  1280х1024. Проблем почти нет. Единственное, что хотелось бы исправить, это видимость всех столбцов в таблице. А в некоторых ячейках текст разбит на несколько строк.
Возможно, в Qt существует функция, которая позволит уменьшить масштаб интерфейса программы до 50% или 75%. На Windows доступны только значения масштабирования 100% и выше.
qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR","значение") - не помогает.
